# A loop that stops for word 4 letter

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I'm tring to stop a loop when i enter a word with 4 letters, but it doesn't stop. What's wrong with it?
Here my code :

```
int main()
{
    char word[10][20];
    int i=0;

    while(strlen(word[i])!=4)
    {
        scanf("%s",&word[i]);
        puts(word[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're checking the `strlen` of `word[i]` before you've read anything into `word[i]`.

Comment: `while(i < 10 && 1 == scanf("%19s", word[i]) && strlen(word[i])!=4) puts(word[i++]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `while(strlen(word[i]) != 4` with `while ((i-1 >= -1) && (strlen(word[i-1]) != 4))`.

Your version is checking the *current word* which is not entered yet. You read a word, increase `i` and compute length of the `i`th word, but it's not here yet, but you wanna check the length of *the last word entered*, so use `word[i-1]` and *add a check (!!) to prevent going out of bounds* (eg. `while ((i-1 >= -1) && strlen(word[i-1]....)`